# How do I add a desktop link to a youtube video?

Tags: chrome-for-android, youtube, home-screen-shortcuts

Normally I can add a desktop link from Chrome by using "Add to Home screen".  However, when I click on a YouTube video, it automatically opens that video in my YouTube app rather than in Chrome.  Thus I no longer have an option to add something to my home screen.

Any ideas?

I am using: 
Android version 7.0 on a Samsung Galaxy S7

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to do this! (It's a bit fiddly).

- Find your YouTube video
- View the website in Desktop mode
- Shorten the URL (using goo.gl)
- Turn off Wi-Fi (so the shortened URL won't get to youtube.com)
- Enter the shortened URL in your address bar on chrome
- You should get a no internet error
- Add that page to your home screen
- Voila! Now enable Wi-Fi again and the icon will link to YouTube in your browser!

Comment: +1. Nice workaround, though I didn't try it out